# How can I determine what libraries are not good on .Net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I am porting a library from .Net Framework to .Net Core **also**. I've been using the Api Portability analyzer to let me know what I need to address. But it's giving me false positives ([example 1](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport/issues/853), [example 2](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport/issues/857)).

Is there an accurate tool that can provide me this info?

[also asked on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e276a21-738b-4a35-9eb7-4bfe06df6cb8/how-can-i-determine-what-libraries-are-not-good-on-net-core?forum=netfxbcl) (if i get an answer there, I'll post it here).

Comment: APIport is somewhat dead now, as most libraries have already been ported. It was never intended to be exhaustive, more a guideline as to how much of your code would need to be rewritten to compile on Core/Standard. And at the end of the day you still have to test your code on the platforms you're targeting anyway.

Comment: @IanKemp Not what I wanted to hear but thank you. Knowing that ApiPort is not dependable lets me know to stop depending on it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a custom tool, you can easily update your library to use target-framework `netstandard2.0` and update all NuGet-Dependencies as well.

If the library fails to compile it means you are using something that is not compatible with .NET-Core.

If you get a warning like `Package XY was compiled with NET461 and might not be compatible ...` it might work or might as well not work.

If there is no warning at all, it means your library only uses base-classes that are in fact compatible with .NET-Core.

There is also a [tool](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) that helps you migrating old-project format to new-project format which makes it much easier.